# Sub menu of menu in navbar using yeti theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yeti

I want to create `sub-menu` of `menu` using `Yeti theme` in `navbar`. I downloaded bootstrap min css for this from here. [yeti](http://bootswatch.com/yeti/#).

Now I need to include submenu of menu like this link (second level link).

[jsfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/4864/)

When I tried it using Yeti I did not get submenu(second level link). I tried it using `jsfiddle`. Link is here.

[jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/4865/).

How can I get it using `yeti` theme?